# Write into a file and open the same file for input

Tags: perl

I was writing a Perl script like below

```
open(FH, '>', "temp.out") or die "cannot open";
select FH;

print "Hello World!";
close FH;

open (FI, "temp.out") or die "cannot open";
while ( <FI> ) {
    print $_;
}
```

Unfortunately when I am running this script I am not getting "Hello World!" printed. This should be an ideal case, isn't it?

However in the `temp.out` file I can see "Hello World!" printed.

I tried using a variable for the filename, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Why did you put the two `select FH;` statements there?

Comment: I think the problem is with select. Without it, it works. see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html for missing flags/bitmasks

Comment: @Sascha: I think you might be getting confused between the two Perl functions called `select`. This is the one with a single argument - which has nothing to do with flags or bitmasks.

Answer (score 5):

Always use `strict` and `warnings` in your scripts, this would have caught the error you encountered:

```
print() on closed filehandle FH at t.pl line 10, <FI> line 1.
```

Your `FH` is still selected after all, even if you closed it. Unless you have a lot of print statements and can somehow isolate your `select` (e.g. select at the start of a function and restore the previous default at the end) I'd say it's preferable to explicitly specify the file handle in the `print` statement.

Comment: Yes. I didn't add that. Not enough time. Take the credit, you are right. :-)

Comment: NP, first is first! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `print $_` goes into a closed file handle. Since you selected `FH` to be the default output file handle, and you closed it, you can't write there any more. In any case, that file handle is not the screen. So even if it was open, you would not see it on the screen.

You need to save STDOUT and reselect it.

```
open(FH,'>',  "temp.out") or die "cannot open";
my $stdout = select FH;
print "Hello World!";
close FH;
select $stdout;  # here
open (FI, "temp.out") or die "cannot open";
while(<FI>){
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: also, enabling warnings would have shown this, with a `print() on closed filehandle` warning on the print.

Comment: Oops. That's what I get for walking away from the screen in the middle of a post :)